# Run a c# Console App with .application file type from a .BAT

Tags: c#, console, batch-file, console-application, command-line-arguments

I've created a console app (using Visual Studio 2010) which can read command arguments.

When I debug, I parse some test parameters which are set in Project-> [project name] Properties... -> Debug -> Command line arguments:

It reads:
"parametername1|parametervalue1" "parametername2|parametervalue2" "parametername3|parametervalue3"

I used the following code to read the parameters:

```
for (Int16 argumentsCount = 0; argumentsCount < args.Length; argumentsCount++)
{
    String[] parameterItem = args[argumentsCount].Split('|');
    String parameterName = parameterItem[0].ToString();
    String parameterValue = parameterItem[1].ToString();
    /*code continues*/

}
```

When I run in debug mode the app it works just fine and all parameters are read.

I then published the app to a server and ensured it was installed with the correct permissions (for the purposes of demonstration lets say it's on C:\MyApp and the Complied code resides in MyApp.application

I then created a batch script that executes the app. The *.BAT contains the following command:

```
"C:\MyApp\MyApp.application" "parametername1|parametervalue1" "parametername2|parametervalue2" "parametername3|parametervalue3"
```

This kind of works as the application executes when I run the batch... However... none of my parameters are being received by my app. I know this because I recompiled and published with some code to read how many parameters are being received with:

```
Console.Write("Arguments " + args.Length.ToString());
```

and that shows Arguments: 0

Can someone please tell me how to write my batch script to run the app and parse my parameters/command line arguments.

Comment: /astandard wayofdoingit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ETA:** Nevermind. Your problem is `.application` instead of a `.exe`. Look in your file associations what happens with `.application` compared to `.exe`:

```
> assoc .application
.application=Application.Manifest

> ftype Application.Manifest
Application.Manifest=rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication %1

> assoc .exe
.exe=exefile

> ftype exefile
exefile="%1" %*
```

You see the difference in what is passed there? Namely that normal executables get command-line arguments (the `%*`). So I guess you should use an executable instead of an executable manifest or whatever `.application` actually is (I've never seen it in the wild, honestly).

---

With a fairly minimal test program

```
class Args {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("[{0}]=<{1}>", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine for me. The following batch file:

```
@"args.exe" "parametername1|parametervalue1" "parametername2|parametervalue2" "parametername3|parametervalue3"
```

yields the following output:

```
[0]=<parametername1|parametervalue1>
[1]=<parametername2|parametervalue2>
[2]=<parametername3|parametervalue3>
```

So I guess there is something wrong in the code you didn't show us. Maybe you're not actually using the command-line arguments in your C# application but instead reference a different `string[]` there?

Comment: Thanks so much guys. My issue was indeed that I was executing the .application file. To get the .exe I simply went in to the project bin/Debug directory and copied the .exe to my deployment directory. I then modified my batch script to execute the .exe and when I ran my batch script again... Hey presto, it worked! So my batch script looked like this in the end: "C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe" "parametername1|parametervalue1" "parametername2|parametervalue2" "parametername3|parametervalue3"

Answer (score -1):

The pipe character `|` has a special meaning in batch files. I would suggest using a different character to make things easier. Otherwise you have to use a [Escape Character](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) to use the pipe character. It would probably look like this:

```
"C:\MyApp\MyApp.application" "parametername1^|parametervalue1" "parametername2^|parametervalue2" "parametername3^|parametervalue3"
```

note the caret `^` before the pipe `|`.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for getting back. I tried using the "^" character but it still doesnt seem to work.

There must be something wrong with my batch script and the way I parse my parameters... I just can't figure it out.

Anyone?

Comment: The `|` is not the problem, as they are correctly quoting it. It gets passed correctly to the application.